# assessing stochastic dominance?

Tags: statistics, rank, economics, stochastic

According to [wikipedia and other scattered software documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) Kruskal Wallis tests assess "stochastic dominance". But which type of stochastic dominance from those discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering)? The original paper cited in that article doesn't even mention "dominance". Nor does Dunn's much-cited 1964 paper. A stata function documentations mention that it tests dominance "that is, the probability that a randomly
drawn observation from one group will be greater than a randomly drawn observation from another." https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1501500117 . How does that relate to formal stochastic dominance, e.g. from decision theory [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering). Can someone help clarifying what approaches there are to assess stochastic dominance (properly-defined) and particulary how and why are they related to Kruskal Wallis type approaches. Or even just a reference which is clear. Many thanks for the pointers!